# Сохранение изображения из галереи в android

Tags: java, android, gallery

у меня возник вопрос при установке изображения в ImageView: при нажатии на него открывается галерея, человек выберет фото, фото устанавливается в профиль, но при следующем запуске приложения или activity ему придётся снова его выбирать. Что нужно сделать, чтобы фото сохранялось в самом приложении или путь к нему? Но тут появляется еще один вопрос: если сохранить путь, а изображение пользователь удалит, то ничего не установиться (я так думаю). Вот Activity

```
public class MyAccountSettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView arrowIm;
CircleImageView profileImage;
private final int Pick_image = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account_settings);
    arrowIm = findViewById(R.id.picArrow);
    profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

    arrowIm.setOnClickListener(this);
    profileImage.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.picArrow:
            intent = new Intent(MyAccountSettingsActivity.this, UserSettings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.profileImage:
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            //Тип получаемых объектов - image:
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            //Запускаем переход с ожиданием обратного результата в виде информации об изображении:
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, Pick_image);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case Pick_image:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    //Получаем URI изображения, преобразуем его в Bitmap
                    //объект и отображаем в элементе ImageView нашего интерфейса:
                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    Log.e("mLog", "onActivityResult: " + imageStream + " " +  imageReturnedIntent + " " + imageUri);
                    profileImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="adwantay.studio.dindon.MyAccountSettingsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="20sp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picArrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_monday_arrow" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_medium"
                android:paddingLeft="25sp"
                android:paddingRight="25sp"
                android:text="@string/my_account"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picDone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_monday_done" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:background="@color/greyAction" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20sp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                        android:layout_width="115dp"
                        android:layout_height="115dp"
                        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                        app:civ_border_width="0dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="15sp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                            android:text="@string/user_name"
                            android:textColor="@color/greyAction"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/userName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/my_account_edit_text"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                            android:paddingLeft="7sp"
                            android:paddingTop="7sp"
                            android:paddingBottom="3sp"
                            android:text="TextView" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView9"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                            android:text="@string/group"
                            android:textColor="@color/greyAction"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/url2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:entries="@array/group"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                            android:paddingLeft="1sp"
                            android:paddingTop="6sp"
                            android:paddingBottom="7sp"
                            android:text="TextView" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                android:text="@string/email"
                android:textColor="@color/greyAction"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/url4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_account_edit_text"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                android:paddingLeft="7sp"
                android:paddingTop="7sp"
                android:paddingBottom="3sp"
                android:text="TextView@mail.ru" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                android:text="@string/safety"
                android:textColor="@color/greyAction"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/hover"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20sp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/picToc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_monday_toc" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                        android:paddingLeft="25sp"
                        android:paddingRight="25sp"
                        android:text="@string/edit_psw"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/account"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/hover"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20sp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/picAccount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_monday_toc" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                        android:paddingLeft="25sp"
                        android:paddingRight="25sp"
                        android:text="@string/two_fact_auth"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/notifications"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/hover"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20sp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/picNotifications"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_monday_toc" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/ttcommons_light"
                        android:paddingLeft="25sp"
                        android:paddingRight="25sp"
                        android:text="@string/deactivate_account"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/palette"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                android:background="@drawable/hover"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20sp">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:background="@drawable/hover"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="20sp">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вот XML

Comment: Путь изображения можно сохранить в базу данных 
А на случай, если пользователь пожелает удалить фото, то можно копировать фото в отдельную скрытую папку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сохранения пути, можно использовать [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). Для этого берем uri выбранной картинки и сохраняем в память:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case Pick_image:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {

                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    ...


                    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    mSettings.edit().putString("path", imageUri.toString()).apply();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

дальше при запуске приложения проверяем есть ли что-то в памяти:

```
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String path = mySharedPreferences.getString("path", "");
if(path != null && !path.trim().isEmpty()){
\\ сетим картинку по сохраненному пути
InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
profileImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
}else{
 \\ картинка не сохранена в памяти
}
```

Для того чтобы проверить есть ли картинка, можно сделать так:

```
File file = new File(URI.create(path).getPath());
 if (file.exists()) {
  \\ картинка существует
 }
```

и вот итоговое решение должно быть приблизительно таким:

```
String path = mySharedPreferences.getString("path", "");
if(path != null && !path.trim().isEmpty()){
File file = new File(URI.create(path).getPath());
if (file.exists()) {
  InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
  Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
  profileImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
 }

}else{
 \\ картинка не сохранена в памяти
}
```